# $f(x+n)$ converges for any $x$ when $n\to +\infty$, then $f(x)$ converges when $x\to +\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity, baire-category

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I have two questions as follows.

1. Suppose that $f(x+n)\to L$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ when $n\to \infty$. Is it guaranteed that $f(x) \to L$ when $x\to +\infty$?

<s>2. Suppose that $f(x+n)$ converges for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ when $n \to \infty$. Is it guaranteed that $f(x)$ converges when $x \to +\infty$?</s> (As pointed out by @Ninad Munshi, the answer is obviously negative by considering a simple example with $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$. Thank @Ninad Munshi.)

Remarks:

1. Here we may require that the limit of any convergence must be a finite number. However, what if we consider a generalized situation that the limit is allowed to be infinity?
2. The question is an additive analogs of [$f(nx)\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778285/fnx-to-0-as-n-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [If $\,\lim_{n\to\infty}f(nx)\,$ exists, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then so does $\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616745/if-lim-n-to-inftyfnx-exists-for-all-x-in-mathbb-r-then-so-does) , and [If $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \ f(\alpha n)$ exists , does this imply $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289712/if-lim-n-to-infty-f-alpha-n-exists-does-this-imply-lim-x-to?rq=1) , which can be solved using Baire's category theorem.

Any comments or criticism will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Remark 1 is backwards. $\sin(2\pi x)$ is a counterexample for the second but not the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)$ denote the function whose graph is an isosceles triangle with base $[0,1/n]$ and height $1$. Specifically:
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
2nx & \text{if }0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2n} \\
2 - 2nx & \text{if }\frac{1}{2n} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and let
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x-n)$$
So, the graph of $f$ consists of a series of increasingly narrow triangles, where the $n$'th triangle has base $[n, n+1/n]$ and height $1$. It's straightforward to verify that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x+n) = 0$$
for all $x$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ does not exist.